# How to ensure a Thread won't delay in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, time

I wrote a multi threading programme, which have two to four thread at the same time.
One of the thread is time critical thread, it will be called every 500 milliseconds, it is not allow to delay more than 10 milliseconds. But when other thread have more loading, I find that some delay, around two millisecond is occurred. (Print the timestamp to show it) So, I worry that after running for a long time it will delay more than 10 milliseconds, except from check the timestamp, and adjust the looping interval to make sure the time is not delay more than 10 milliseconds, is there any way to make it safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need [Real-Time Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-rtj1/)

Comment: I don't think that'll help OP. It's some heavy WebSphere crud. I don't think there are any good realtime Java solutions out there, really.

Comment: Well I could have given this link: http://www.rtsj.org/ but I thought the WebSphere site did a good job summarizing the concept (also it's a reference implementation of the same JSR [JSR-1 actually]).  I'm afraid I don't have much experience working with it, is there something about RTSJ that doesn't work?

Comment: It's still at specification level and open research, as far as I know. IBM's solution may even be worth some salt, but it very probably ties you into IBM's stranglehold.

Answer (score 2):

If timing is critical, I use a busy wait on a core which is dedicated to that thread.  This can give you << 10 micro-second jitter most of the time.  Its a bit extreme and will result in the logical thread not being used for anything else.

This is the library I use. You can use it to reserve a logical thread or a whole core. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity

By using isolcpus= in grub.conf on Linux you can ensure that the logical thread or core is not used for any else (except the 100 Hz timer and power management which are relatively small and < 2 us delay)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your threads priorities:

```
myCriticalThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
otherThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY); // the default
yetAnotherThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
```

It won't really guarantee anything though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that your thread isn't delayed, because the OS may decide to give other processes precedence (unless you put effort in setting up a complete real-time system including a modified OS). That being said, for basic tasks, you should use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) like this:

```
class A {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService exe = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  public void startCriticalAction(Runnable command) {
    this.exe.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    this.exe.shutdown();
  }
}
```

The executor service will do its best to execute the task every 100ms. You should not develop this functionality yourself, because a lot of things can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Creep up on the timeout:

```
waitFor(int timeout)
{
  dateTime wallTimeEnd;
  wallTimeEnd=now()+(msToDateTime(timeout));
  int interval=timeout/2;
  while(true){
    if(interval>10){
      sleep(interval);
      interval=dateTimeToMs(wallTimeEnd-now()) / 2;
    } 
      else
      {
        do{
          sleep(0);
          interval=dateTimeToMs(wallTimeEnd-now());
        }while(interval>0);
  }
}
```

This only wastes a core for 5-10ms